# Cuda compiling error when coming to g++ compiling step

Tags: cuda

```
nvcc -D_DEBUG --use_fast_math -I"/usr/local/cuda-9.0//include" -I"/usr/include/eigen3" -I"/home/xingfu/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/common/inc" -dlink --machine 64 -arch=sm_50 -c -o kernel_cuda.o ../CudaTest/kernel.cu

g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../CudaTest -I. -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -I../NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/common/inc -isystem /usr/local/include -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o LBDM.o ../CudaTest/LBDM.cpp
```

The two steps above have passed, however, when run the following step, the error occured:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/xingfu/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -o CudaTest kernel_cuda.o LBDM.o   -L/usr/local/cuda-9.0//lib64/ -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -L/home/xingfu/CudaTest/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -L/home/xingfu/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread
```

The compiler error shows:

```
kernel_cuda.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00000e7d_00000000-5_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x177e): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_41_tmpxft_00000e7d_00000000_6_kernel_cpp1_ii_channel'
```

How can I fix the error?

---

What's more, 
I add the -dlink, because it shows the error when dealing the following step:

```
nvcc -D_DEBUG --use_fast_math -I"/usr/local/cuda-9.0//include" -I"/usr/include/eigen3" -I"/home/xingfu/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/common/inc" --machine 64 -arch=sm_50 -c -o kernel_cuda.o ../CudaTest/kernel.cu
```

and the error is:

```
ptxas fatal : Unresolved extern function 'cublasCreate_v2'
```

However, when I add -dlink, the error occured like I said above.

BTW, before I add -dlink, I can run a simple function in another test project like this:

```
__global__ void add(float* x, float * y, float* z, int n)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
    {
        z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
    }
}
```

After I add -dlink, the test project shows an error:

```
cuda_code_cuda.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_000017db_00000000-5_cuda_code.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x861): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_44_tmpxft_000017db_00000000_6_cuda_code_cpp1_ii_5b538d80'
```

which is very similar to the above error.

Comment: My gcc and g++ version are both 4.8.5. My system is ubuntu18.04.

Comment: Cuda version is 9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [relocatable device code linking](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-options-for-separate-compilation), which seems to be what you're after, the recommended sequence would be as follows.  In addition, it appears your code is attempting to use the cublas device interface, so for good measure we'll add those libraries to the link steps:

```
#replace -dlink -c with -dc
nvcc -D_DEBUG --use_fast_math -I"/usr/local/cuda-9.0//include" -I"/usr/include/eigen3" -I"/home/xingfu/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/common/inc" -dc --machine 64 -arch=sm_50 -o kernel_cuda.o ../CudaTest/kernel.cu

#generate device-linked object with cublas device libraries
nvcc -D_DEBUG --use_fast_math  -dlink --machine 64 -arch=sm_50 -o kernel_dlink.o kernel_cuda.o -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt

#no change to this line
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../CudaTest -I. -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -I../NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/common/inc -isystem /usr/local/include -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o LBDM.o ../CudaTest/LBDM.cpp

#add device-linked object to final link phase plus cublas device libraries
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/xingfu/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -o CudaTest kernel_cuda.o LBDM.o kernel_dlink.o  -L/usr/local/cuda-9.0//lib64/ -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -L/home/xingfu/CudaTest/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -L/home/xingfu/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread
```